# SQL Consulta subquery nivel

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo una consulta que arroja error de nivel.
Es una tabla que tiene las tasas de cambio en dos direcciones
Ejemplo:

```
moneda_from | moneda_to | tasa conversion
        ARS |   USD     | 0.20
        USD |   ARS     | 20.00
```

Quiero obtener uno de los juegos, por ejemplo, el de mayor valor

```
moneda_from | moneda_to | tasa conversion
        USD |   ARS     | 20.00
```

En la tabla, obviamente, hay muchas combinaciones de distintas monedas y la consulta siguiente resolvería el problema, pero no llega al segundo nivel

```
select *
from gl.gl_daily_rates gdr
where  gdr.conversion_date = to_date('20180301','YYYYMMDD')
and    gdr.conversion_rate = (select max(total.conversion_rate)
                              from   (select gdr2.conversion_rate
                                      from   gl.gl_daily_rates gdr2
                                      where  gdr2.conversion_date = gdr.conversion_date
                                      and    gdr2.from_currency   = gdr.from_currency
                                      and    gdr2.to_currency     = gdr.to_currency
                                      union all
                                      select gdr3.conversion_rate
                                      from   gl.gl_daily_rates gdr3
                                      where  gdr3.conversion_date = gdr.conversion_date
                                      and    gdr3.from_currency   = gdr.to_currency
                                      and    gdr3.to_currency     = gdr.from_currency
                                      ) total);
```

A alguien se le ocurre como se puede resolver? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Me respondieron esta pregunta en [SQL Query subquery (second level)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333338/sql-query-subquery-second-level)
y me han pasado una respuesta en ingles, la manera de hacer lo que solicito es:

```
select *
from (select gdr.*,
             max(conversion_rate) over (partition by least(currency_from, currency_to), greatest(currency_from, currency_to) ) as max_cr
      from gl.gl_daily_rates gdr
      where gdr.conversion_date = to_date('20180301','YYYYMMDD') 
     ) gdr
where conversion_rate = max_cr;
```

Gracias a @gordon-linoff